# Add number to the middle of url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

tcpdf.org/

basically I want to launch a page on my desktop for example index.html

then all I want to see is a textbox and a submit button.
so when I input a number and click submit the code would insert that number into a url

Example: if I entered '52314' and clicked submit, the link below would open in browser.

```
192.168.1.50/tcpdf/autoview/serviceinvoice.php?SERVICEINVOICE=52314&COMPANY=1
```

I have found scripts online that add text to the end of a url but I need to enter it in the middle of the address.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In the middle.... Where?!

Comment: when I say in the middle I mean after 'SERVICEINVOICE=' and before '&COMPANY=1'   AsI indicated in the example. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just switch the `GET` parameters around so the number is at the end of the URL.

Change from:

`192.168.1.50/tcpdf/autoview/serviceinvoice.php?SERVICEINVOICE=52314&COMPANY=1`

to

`192.168.1.50/tcpdf/autoview/serviceinvoice.php?COMPANY=1&SERVICEINVOICE=52314`

And you're done.

Comment: thank seems to work alright. I have not finished the code but if I move the parameters around in the browser and hit enter I get the result I need.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you had the string:

```
var template = "192.168.1.50/tcpdf/autoview/serviceinvoice.php?SERVICEINVOICE=NUM_HERE&COMPANY=1";
```

You can insert the number easily with a simple JS `replace()`:

```
var id = 52314; // inputted number
var url = template.replace("NUM_HERE", id);
```

---

Actually, even easier, you can just concatenate the strings:

```
var id = 52314; // inputted number
var url = "192.168.1.50/tcpdf/autoview/serviceinvoice.php?SERVICEINVOICE=" + id + "&COMPANY=1"
```

Comment: Thanks for an instant response.

again I have the same issue as the other answer, should I add the code to a text editor then save the code as .html or .php?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in PHP you could add the following form to index.html

```
<form action="redirect.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="SERVICEINVOICE"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The action is redirect.php so create script redirect.php and add

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $urlBase = '/tcpdf/autoview/serviceinvoice.php';
    // todo validate post variables based on your requirements and to ensure security depending on your framework
    $serviceInvoice = $_POST['SERVICEINVOICE'];
    $url = $urlBase.'?SERVICEINVOICE='.$serviceInvoice.'&COMPANY=1';
    // Redirect browser
    header("Location: ".$url);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply.  I opened up notepad+ added your code then saved it as test.php

but when I open it I just see the code, I was expecting to see a text box.  what can I do to the code to see the text box?

Comment: I did not provide the html form, only the php code to redirect the user to the desired url on submit of the form.

Comment: Could you help me with the html part or is that too basic to ask the coders here?

I just need a text box to allow me enter a number then a submit button were your code comes into play.
Thanks

Comment: It's not too basic but there is an expectation that you would attempt to write your own code

Comment: I had the box code written its just linking it up with your php.

thanks for all your help.